# System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager cannot parse system.diagnostics section in App.config

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to load appsettings from the App.config file which has the format of this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="something" value="hello"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

and my console app looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var something = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("something");
            Console.WriteLine(something);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

During the runtime, ConfigurationManager throws a exception states that

```
Configuration system failed to initialize
```

Which has the inner error message of this:

```
"Unrecognized configuration section system.diagnostics."
```

My code is running on linux with .net core v2.1 installed, and I downloaded the Configuration.ConfigurationManger from Nuget. Does anyone know what is going on here? Looks like the .net core has some issues when parsing the config file.

Comment: On Windows this normally happens if you have edited/removed/broke the machine.config file. Not sure how this works on Linux.

Comment: Since .Net core won't automatically do anything with system.diagnostics, maybe it's worth just deleting it? I guess it's just not supported out of the box in this package

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik, if that's the case, how should I set up the system.diagnostics? I use the system.diagnostics to add sharedListensers

Comment: You should do it programmatically I assume since .net core does not by default know anything about web.config or app.config. So even if you load something from app.config, it won't do the default configuration like the old .net would